# Is there a discrete relationship shared between patterns and series or sequences?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Maybe to clarify a little, I feel that patterns are related to sequences and series, in that a series or sequence can define a pattern. However I have yet to find any reference to such being the case mathematically. Can anybody refer me to a source that either proves, disproves, or otherwise discusses any sort of relationship between patterns and series or sequences?

By pattern, I mean numeric list of numbers that are related by a mathematical operation. The operation may be arithmetic or geometric. The operation may also being simple or complicated.

For example, I can define numeric patterns using sequences, such as the Fibonacci sequence, which is, under my definition, an arithmetic pattern.

So I think that sequences, at least, are numeric patterns under my definition.

My question is should all numeric patterns also be sequences?

And one reason I ask is that in a mathematics teaching book I found for children, a pattern is described that does not fit this definition. The pattern first adds some number to an initial value, something like +2010, and to the result the pattern then adds +2210, and then +2010, and assumes in the answer guide that the next repetition adds +2210.

This diverges from my thinking when it comes to patterns. Can this sort of pattern be defined as a sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern"?

Comment: For your example, to define the pattern as a sequence you might use $a(n) = a(n-1) + 2010 + 200*(n \% 2)$. There's not necessarily a reason to suggest that the next number in the sequence HAS to be +2210, but absent any other available information it's a reasonable choice for continuing the pattern. Although consider if the sequence had been instead $a(n) = a(n-1)+2010+200*(f(n))$ where $f(n)$ is the fibonacci sequence starting with the unconventional $1,0,1,1,2,...$ The initial three terms would still be identical.

Comment: So it sounds like the answer to my last question is yes. I'm just not thinking hard enough about how to derive a(n), and the pattern is in fact geometric.